# How to determine basis and dimension of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I'm new into linear algebra and I encountered the following problem:

> In $\mathbb{R}^4$ we conside the following subspaces: $U=\{(x.y.z.w)\in \mathbb{R}^4 | x+y+z=0\}$, $V=\mathscr{L}((1,1,0,0), (2,-1,0,1),(4,1,0,1)).$
>
> 1. Determine the basis and dimensions of U, V and an algebraic representation of V.
> 2. Determine the basis and dimensions of $U \cap V$ and $U+V$.
> 3. Complete the base of $U \cap V$ in a base of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Firstly, I know that the subspace U is the set of solutions of the linear equation $x+y+z=0$ . But now I'm stuck as I have never seen such type of  problem and don't really understand what should I do.

Can someone explain in detail the steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Firstly note that $U$ has dimension $3$ since we have three free variables, thus to find a base we can consider the three linearly independent vectors

- $(x,y,z,w)=(1,-1,0,1) $
- $(x,y,z,w)=(1,0,-1,1)$
- $(x,y,z,w)=(0,1,-1,1)$

Can you proceed from here?